# Pythonic way to group a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, glob

So lets say I have a hypothetical list of lists of file names in `Python` defined like so:

```
l = [["user1/stats1.csv", "user1/stats2.csv", "user1/stats3.csv"], 
    ["user2/stats1.csv", "user2/stats2.csv", "user2/stats3.csv"]]
```

What would be the most pythonic way to group it by the number in `statsN.csv` such that the list would look like:

```
l = [["user1/stats1.csv", "user2/stats1.csv"], 
    ["user1/stats2.csv", "user2/stats2.csv"],
    ["user1/stats3.csv", "user2/stats3.csv"],
```

For reference, the original list was obtained by using `glob` with the `*` wild card a la `glob.glob("user1/stats*.csv")` and `glob.glob("user2/stats*.csv")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpack the sublists and `zip`:

```
out = list(map(list, zip(*l)))
```

Output:

```
[['user1/stats1.csv', 'user2/stats1.csv'],
 ['user1/stats2.csv', 'user2/stats2.csv'],
 ['user1/stats3.csv', 'user2/stats3.csv']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy, you can simply transpose:

```
>>> np.array(l).T.tolist()
[['user1/stats1.csv', 'user2/stats1.csv'],
 ['user1/stats2.csv', 'user2/stats2.csv'],
 ['user1/stats3.csv', 'user2/stats3.csv']]
```